# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click' using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am not able to accept the cookie button it is always showing me error as:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Also my browser is getting closed automatically.

Snapshot of the code and error:

[image: Code Image]

Comment: Post your code and error message as text, not images. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/).

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you have used:

```
cookie_accept = driver.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value="Sign in")
```

doesn't identify any element within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). Hence *`cookie_accept`* remains *NULL*. So you can't invoke click on the NULL object and you see the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

---

### Solution

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://hub.knime.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.accept-button.button.primary"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://hub.knime.com/')  
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'login or register')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: knime]